# Trouble Executing SQL Stored Procedure C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, console-application

Im trying to execute the following query from a console application.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main.usp_setup
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY
        EXEC main.usp_importXml[C:\Users\User\Desktop\people.xml];
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO main.errorLog(EntryTime,ErrorNumber,ErrorMessage,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLineNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState)
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ERROR_NUMBER(),'Failed to import XML',ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE())  
            declare @message nvarchar(45);
            set @message = 'Failed at Import XML - ' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY()AS NVARCHAR(32)) ;
            THROW 50001,@message , 20;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
        EXEC main.usp_afterimport;
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO main.errorLog(EntryTime,ErrorNumber,ErrorMessage,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLineNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState)
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ERROR_NUMBER(),'Failed to Populate',ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE())    

            set @message = 'Failed to Populate' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY()AS NVARCHAR(32)) ;
            THROW 50001,@message , 20;
        END CATCH
        COMMIT
    END
GO
```

Code in Console Application :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=DELLC;" +
            "Initial Catalog=hr;" +
            "User id=geordey;" +
            "Password=1234;";
            conn.Open();



  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("main.usp_setup", conn);
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        if(a==-1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Loaded");
                        }
```

But when executed the following error is given:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The current transaction cannot be
>   committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file.
>   Roll back the transaction.
>
> Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The
>   transaction is rolled back.'

Comment: don't you miss an "END" before the "GO" ?

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC main.usp_importXml[C:\Users\User\Desktop\people.xml];
BND TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   INSERT INTO ...
END CATCH
COMMIT
```

You absolutely cannot do this. Inside a CATCH block you **must** check for the [`XACT_STATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql) value and act accordingly:

> - 1   The current request has an active user transaction. The request can perform any actions, including writing data and committing the transaction.
> - 0   There is no active user transaction for the current request.
> - -1  The current request has an active user transaction, but an error has occurred that has caused the transaction to be classified as an uncommittable transaction.

Not only that, but you cannot place the COMMIT **after** the CATCH. If the transaction has rolled back, what are you going to commit? You should place the COMMIT before the CATCH, and you can have only *one* TRY/CATCH block, not two.

If you want a good pattern to model after, read [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/):

```
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
go
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing an END before the COMMIT call.

See my answer below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main.usp_setup
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
REPEATABLE READ
BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
        EXEC main.usp_importXml[C:\Users\User\Desktop\people.xml];
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO main.errorLog(EntryTime,ErrorNumber,ErrorMessage,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLineNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState)
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ERROR_NUMBER(),'Failed to import XML',ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE())  
            declare @message nvarchar(45);
            set @message = 'Failed at Import XML - ' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY()AS NVARCHAR(32)) ;
            THROW 50001,@message , 20;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
        EXEC main.usp_afterimport;
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO main.errorLog(EntryTime,ErrorNumber,ErrorMessage,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLineNumber,ErrorSeverity,ErrorState)
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,ERROR_NUMBER(),'Failed to Populate',ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE())    

            set @message = 'Failed to Populate' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY()AS NVARCHAR(32)) ;
            THROW 50001,@message , 20;
        END CATCH
COMMIT
GO
```

Comment: I have tried it your way and the error is still showing :/

Comment: please try now should ne fixed

Comment: the problem is *way* more complex than just BEGIN/END syntax match. Read up about [uncommitable transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql).

Comment: You are correct @RemusRusanu seems like there was an error inside your try block, and thus it results in uncommitable state where only rollback could help you survive that situation.